# AngularJS page content based on routing params (same view)

Tags: angularjs

I have my main view, home, with links to another view, download.
I have two buttons on my home view, 'Free trial' and 'download', both of which point to the download view, but I want the first paragraph of the download view to be determined by a parameter distinguishing the two buttons.

How do I go about achieving this? I thought maybe use two controllers, but I am new to AngularJS and wondered whether there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood you correctly...

It is possible in theory to have both pages managed by the same controller, but that is not best practice if they are 2 separate views, and in any case, controllers are assumed to be short-lived. The "angular way" of passing data between controllers is services. So you would do something like this:

```
app.factory('DownloadType',function() {
   return {
      type:"free"  
   };
   // just used "free" as a default
})
.controller('Home',function($scope,DownloadType) {
   $scope.setType = function(type) {
      DownloadType.type = type;
   };
})
.controller('Download',function($scope,DownloadType) {
   $scope.type = DownloadType.type;
})
;
```

And then your home template could look like:

```
<button ng-click="setType('free')">Free</button>
<button ng-click="setType('paid')">Paid</button>
```

And your download template

```
<div ng-show="type === 'free'">This is a free download</div>
<div ng-show="type === 'paid'">You are paying us! We love you!</div>
```

There are somewhat cleaner ways, e.g. if you wanted a single click to go to the page and set it:

```
.controller('Home',function($scope,$location,DownloadType) {
   $scope.setType = function(type) {
      DownloadType.type = type;
      $location.path('/download');
   };
})
```

Finally, if you wanted them on a single view, then you don't need the service at all, because you have a single view with a single controller.

Comment: What if I want to do it with a single controller? I'm pretty new to AngularJS. How can I transfer the value of the DownloadType between views with the same controller? Everytime I move to the download view, the Home controller resets...

Comment: You could, but why would you? Realize that it means that *everything* in the scope will be shared between the views, and things could trounce. If you want to, though, and accept that it is a single view, then you can.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be done by using nested-views with ui-router. Sample code,

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
})
    .state('product', {
        url: "/product",
  templateUrl: "templates/product.html"
    })
.state('product.trial', {
  url: "/product/trial",
  templateUrl: "templates/product.trial.html"
})
.state('product.download', {
  url: "/product/download",
  templateUrl: "templates/product.download.html"
})
```

Now inside product.trial.html & product.download.html, place your first paragraph only & in the product.html, place this code::::

```
//the code snippet that is common for all views....
<div ui-view>
```